# Setup.bash and Arch Linux

Tags: ros, archlinux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm a new Ros-user. I installed it with success, but I have a problem. When I give in input in my shell `source ~/ros/setup.bash` I obtain as answer this:

*Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 17, in    File "", line 17, in  TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing rospack could not be found, you cannot have rosbash features until you bootstrap ros*

And nothing works. If I type the command again all works and I don't receive any error messages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30861/setup.bash-and-arch-linux/) by [Andrea](https://answers.ros.org/users/2086/andrea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-03-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

IIRC, Arch Linux has Python 3 by default, which creates compatibility issues with ROS.  I am not an Arch user, but I imagine some bug tickets (and patches) are necessary to be compatible with Arch in this case.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I experienced similar problems. The solution, at least for setup.sh, is change line 13 to point python2 instead of python3, just by changing that line to this

```
export _PARSED_CONFIG=`/usr/bin/env python2 << EOPYTHON
```

---

Originally posted by [Erwin Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/2189/erwin-lopez/) with karma: 11 on 2012-05-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1